# What are the adminhtml frontend and install directories under app/design each doing?

Tags: magento

I'm extremely new to magento I've come to understand that all of the front end code is stored under app/design and skin with my new magento install I found three directories adminhtml, frontend and install. I'm just wondering if anyone could explain what each directory is for and which are relevant to the default theme. Do I need to keep all the directories?

Answer (score 0):

You're almost right in your comment that *all* of the frontend code is stored in app/design. This is where the template and layout files are stored. There is also the ./skin folder in the root of your Magento installation, where the javascript and css files can be stored.

As for you actual question, all of the folder should be kept right where they are, Magento is a fragile little child that shouldn't be disturbed too much if not necessary.

The 'install' folder is used as a theme for when you are installing your Magento installation through the browser (it is also possible to do this via terminal, search for 'n98-magerun' if you're interested in this).

After the installation, Magento sees the user interface frontend (what the customer sees) and the user interface backend (what the shop owner can see) as 2 different themes. The 'frontend' folder is used to store all templates etc to style/theme/anything the frontend, whereas the 'adminhtml' folder is used to style/theme/anything the backend. This is necessary if you want to add your own menu's in the backend with a little bit more styling/stuff than the regular Magento theme.

tl;dr

'frontend' is frontend stuff which the customer sees

'adminhtml' is frontend stuff which the shopowner sees in the backend system

Hope this answers your question! :)

Kind regards, 
Tom